# CSS: Responsive CSS not working on different browser

Tags: css, responsive-design

i have develop my own site and applied the following CSS:

```
.entry-content li,p {
font-size: 17pt;
font-family : Times new roman;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.entry-content li,p {
font-size: 14pt;
font-family : Times new roman;
}
.et_pb_post h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
}
```

the mentioned CSS above worked on google chrome. but when i view the site using mozilla firefox, the `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {` is not working.

how to resolve this ?
how to resolve this with various browser such as safari, opera, thunderbird, etc ?

thanks !

solved, here is my current cSS. tested on Google Chrome and mozilla firefox. (i stil need to test on various browser, though):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.entry-content li,p {
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family : "Times new roman";
}
.et_pb_post h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps Firefox doesn't like `font-family : Times new roman;` without quotes. Try changing it to `font-family : "Times new roman";`

Comment: Works for me, man.  What exactly goes wrong? http://jsbin.com/peviqugajo/1

Comment: `...but when i view the site using mozilla firefox, the @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { is not working.` That's not true. Tell us the steps to reproduce, but firefox works with mediaqueries when Chrome was in pregnant.

Comment: i change my css into what @PierreDuc suggest. and now it works on mozilla firefox and google chrome. the step to reproduce was apply the css with `Times new roman` (not the `"Times new roman"`) . and click restore button on my mozilla firefox, resize them into smaller screen

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your issue was the lack of quotes around a font-family with spaces.

So `font-family : Times new roman;` must be changed to `font-family : "Times new roman";`. It seems like Firefox likes that better. Which is normal, because it is correct `css`

Comment: do you mean, we should use quotes `"` when there's a space character on font-family name ?

Comment: Yes, exactly: If a font name contains white-space, it must be quoted.